# To convert month name into month number using CONVERT() in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this is a repeated question but i couln't find answer to my problem.

I am trying to get 03-FEB-2014 as 03-02-2014 .I am using below query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,CREATED,105) from dbstatus
```

but its throwing following error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
SELECT CONVERT(date,CREATED,105) from dbstatus
Error at Command Line:1 Column:15
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

"CREATED" is name of a column having dates as 03-FEB-2014

Comment: CONVERT() provides a way to convert data between different character sets. You will not achieve what you want with it.

Comment: I don't think convert does what you think it does...

Comment: `CONVERT(date,CREATED,105)` would be the usage for T-SQL not MySQL

Comment: try this `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) AS [MM-DD-YYYY]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select `to_date(date_column,'YYYY-MM-DD')` then apply `to_char(date_column,'YYYY-MM-DD')`

```
--03-FEB-2014 as 03-02-2014
select to_char( to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy'),'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.simple yet effective

Answer (score 0):

Don't use convert. Convert it used for converting between character sets.

Instead use `MONTHNAME` for what you want: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname

EDIT: Actually, I think what you're trying to do is turn FEB into 02. If that is the case you can use this to do so:

`month(str_to_date('Feb','%b'))`

This will return 2 which you can then `CONCAT` into your date.